# Broken terminal autocomplete with "TAB"

Tags: 16.04, command-line, headless

After some manipulations (i don't know, which excatly did it) i unexpectedly broke terminal autocomplete feature. Each time i try yo use it i get:

```
nimga@ubuntu17:~$ sudo systemctl res-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
bash: _upvars: `-a4': invalid number specifier
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
bash: _upvars: `-a0': invalid number specifier
```

According to text above i tried to autocomplete "sudo systemctl restart" but got an error.
What can i do with it?

Comment: What's the output of `stat /dev/null`?

Comment: File: '/dev/null'
  Size: 28              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 515         Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-07-13 07:42:05.193600092 +0300
Modify: 2017-07-13 14:35:01.493288395 +0300
Change: 2017-07-13 14:35:01.493288395 +0300
 Birth: -

Comment: You broke your `/dev/null`. See dupe on how to fix it.

Comment: Did as it mentioned in dupe, but nothing changed.

Comment: `stat /dev/null` is still the same?

Comment: Executed commands from root and it solved the problem. After user's execution permissions were not proper. Thanks for help!